# Column 'type' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

> Column 'type' cannot be part of
> FULLTEXT index

Что это за ошибка? Я всего-лишь хочу изменить поле varchar на int и всё.

Comment: А как может быть fulltext index по целому числу? Найдите, где у вас для этой колонки прописан индекс.

Comment: @VladD, так в том то и дело, что я даже хочу сбросить его: ALTER TABLE `notifications` DROP INDEX `FULLTEXT`, а в ответ: #1091 - Can't DROP 'FULLTEXT'; check that column/key exists

Comment: @ModaL: `drop index TYPE`? Fulltext -- это не имя колонки, это характеристика индекса.

Comment: @VladD, выполнил запрос ALTER TABLE notifications DROP INDEX `TYPE`, но при изменении varchar на int всё та же ошибка: Column 'type' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index

Comment: @ModaL: хм, а что говорит `SHOW CREATE TABLE notifications`? Или вы забыли `commit`?

Comment: @VladD, http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1358525464-clip-14kb.png

Comment: @ModaL: тогда видимо `DROP INDEX type_5`?

Comment: @VladD, даа! Оформите в виде ответа Ваш вариант и я помечу его верным!

Comment: @ModaL: готово :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Выношу из комментариев)

Нужно сначала убрать fulltext index для интересующей нас колонки. Имя индекса можно посмотреть при помощи команды

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE notifications
```

Команда [показала](http://clip2net.com/clip/m40641/1358525464-clip-14kb.png) наличие индекса с именем `type_5`, поэтому используем

```
ALTER TABLE notifications DROP INDEX type_5
```

Comment: @VladD, спасибо большое!

Comment: @ModaL: пожалуйста!